# WSO2 Migration issue

Tags: wso2-api-manager

in migrating from a WSO2 system to new one, is it possible to keep origin base token of users? or Is it possible to generate Consumer Key & Consumer Secret manually in the new WSO2 system for users?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have few options here.

1. Migrate complete setup

You can use the migration guides[1] and do the complete migration. In here you can use the existing consumer keys and secrets. Basically DB is migrated in here you can use the existing data.

2. Migrate only the APIs

You can use the Open API definition and create the API from scratch in the new APIM setup. Then you can get new consumer keys and secrets.

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/upgrading-wso2-api-manager/400-to-410/upgrading-from-400-to-410/#steps-to-migrate-to-wso2-api-m-410

Comment: Unfortunatly the old data is lost. I just have my client`s base token. So I can extract their old consumer keys and secrets. is there any option to import their consumer keys and secrets into the new WSO ??

Comment: Yes, that is also possible. Please refer - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/oauth2/provisioning-out-of-band-oauth-clients/#provisioning-out-of-band-oauth2-clients

Comment: You can basically provide your consumer key and secret with this.